# Rscript doesn´t plot matlines properly

Tags: r, bash, plot, rscript

I'm trying to run an **R-script** from **bash** to plot a **.png-image** (R version 3.0.2 on MacOSX10.6.8). Therefore I'm using the command

`R CMD BATCH script.R`.

Surprisingly this generates a .png-file including everything, but the matlines. More specifically it plots one single black matline, representing the first of eight defined (colored) matlines. If I call **R** from the bash command line and copy/paste the code from the R-script in all matlines are plotted properly.

The R-script contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

temp.table <- read.table("/path/to/firstTable.txt", 
header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="-999.66", dec=".", 
strip.white=TRUE)

colbind <- cbind(temp.table$column1,temp.table$column2,temp.table$column3,temp.table$column4,temp.table$column5,temp.table$column6,temp.table$column7)

colbind.cor <- colbind + 4.7

time <- 1:1020

table.n <- cbind(time,colbind.cor)

colnames(table.n) <- c("time","column1","column2","column3","column4","column5","column6","column7")


para.col <- read.table("/path/to/secondTable.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", na.strings="-999.66", dec=",", strip.white=TRUE)

png("/path/to/plot/plot.png", width = 800, height = 400)

plot(table.n, axes=F, xlim=c(0,1020+1), ylim=c(5,40), type='l', ann=F)

par(tcl= -0.2)
axis(2, at=seq(5, 40, by=1), labels=F, lwd=1, lwd.ticks=1)

par(tcl= -0.5)
axis(2, at=seq(5, 1 + 40, by=5), labels=seq(5,40,5), lwd=0, lwd.ticks=2)

par(tcl= -0.2)
axis(1, at=seq(1, 1020, by=10), labels=F, lwd=1, lwd.ticks=1)

par(tcl= -0.5)
axis(1, at=seq(1, 1 + 1020, by=60), labels=seq(0,1020/60,1), lwd=0, lwd.ticks=2)

abline(v=(seq(0,1020,60))+1, col="lightgray", lty="dotted")
abline(h=(seq(5,40,2)), col="lightgray", lty="dotted")

title(sub="title", ylab="Temperature [°C]", xlab="time [min]")

matlines (para.col$column8, type = "l", lty = 1:1, lwd = 1, pch = NULL, col=("#00E1FF"))

matlines (table.n[,c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)], type = "l", lty = 1:1, lwd = 1, pch = NULL, col=(c("#FF0000","#FF9D00","#A31E00","#362F2A","#B3B3B3","#F5A882","#128794")))

legend("bottomright",legend = c("column1","column2","column3","column4","column5","column6","column7","column8"), lty=c(1,1), lwd=c(2.5,2.5), col=c("#FF0000","#FF9D00","#A31E00","#362F2A","#B3B3B3","#F5A882","#00E1FF","#128794"), text.font=2, cex=0.64) 

dev.off()

rm(list=ls())
```

I read about problems regarding executability, but neither using chmod 755 on script.R nor deleting the first line (#!/usr/bin/env Rscript) seem to change anything on just getting a single black matline. Installation was done via the R-3.0.2.pkg from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old/), but the same problem occurred using the former version.

I would be really grateful for any helping ideas!

PS: Note that this script requires external input from 2 tables (**firstTable.txt** and **secondTable.txt**). Both tables are downloadable as **zipped txt-files** at [filedropper.com/firstandsecondtable](http://filedropper.com/firstandsecondtable).

Comment: Please edit your example such that (1) It runs on my machine without editing, (2) It reproduces the problem you are trying to fix. For example, I get this error `cannot open file '/path/to/first/table.txt': No such file or directory` and no output.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I uploaded the content of the first and second table at http://txtup.net/vZarN (**firstTable part1**), http://txtup.net/buMlM (**firstTable part2**) and http://txtup.net/mEceI (**secondTable full**). firstTable is divided into 2 parts for reasons of character limitations at TextUploader.com.

Comment: To make it a bit more straight forward **both tables** are downloadable as **zipped txt-files** at http://www.filedropper.com/firstandsecondtable. Please excuse the confusion.